# How to prevent css from coloring an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a sign up form, and when the password & confirm password match, the sign up button turns green on hover, but when you hover over the button when it's green and delete a number from the password field (so the password & confirm don't match) and you move away the mouse the button remains green instead of changing back to it's original color.

Button is green when passwords match
[image] 
Button remains green when passwords don't match
[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/makeyka/pen/oVQPOV

HTML:

```
<form>
<p class="font"><span id="movePassword">Password</span></p>

<input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Password..'" required>

<p class="font"><span id="movePassword">Confirm Password</span></p>

<input id="confirm_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm.." onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Confirm..'" onkeyup="check();" required><span id="msg"></span>

<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" id="submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#msg {
    left: 3%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

#submit {
    position: relative;
    left: 3%;
    width: 120px;
    color: #4e5463; 
    background-color: #e8ecf7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
    var check = function() {

   if (document.getElementById("password").value == document.getElementById("confirm_password").value) {
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = "#009FFD"; // Green
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "&#10004"; // Sign
       document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false; // Able to login (passwords match)

       $("#submit").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css("background", "#009FFD").css("borderRadius", "10px").css("color", "#423d3d"); // Green button background

       }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#e8ecf7").css("borderRadius", "0px").css("color", "#4e5463"); // Button default background color
       });

   } else {
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = "red"; 
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "&#9888"; // Sign
       document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true; // Unable to login (passwords do not match)
   }

}
```

Comment: By the way, the color you are displaying is blue not green. Not trying to make fun if you're color blind but it may be confusing to some.
https://www.color-hex.com/color/009ffd

Comment: Oh right it is blue, I'm using night light so for me it was green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benjamin's description about the mouseenter and mouseleave events are right on, and his use of the `:hover` pseudo-class is indeed the way to handle it, but I like to keep the styles out of the javascript too; instead of manipulating the `.style` on an element, I prefer to set classes describing the state of things, then use CSS.

You can do this with almost all CSS and just the tiniest bit of javascript.
Below, all I do is toggle the classes `valid` and `invalid` on the `<form>` element, and enable/disable the submit button. Everything else is done with styles applied based on whether the form is `.valid` or `.invalid`

```js
// Get the elements we're going to use just once.
let password = document.getElementById('password');
let confirm  = document.getElementById('confirm_password');
let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
let form = password.parentElement;

let check = function() {
    if (password.value === confirm.value) {
        form.classList.remove('invalid');
        form.classList.add('valid');
        submit.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        form.classList.remove('valid');
        form.classList.add('invalid');
        submit.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```css
#msg {
    left: 3%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

#submit {
    position: relative;
    left: 3%;
    width: 120px;
    color: #4e5463; 
    background-color: #e8ecf7;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form.valid #msg:before {
    content: '\2714';
    color: #009FFD;
}
form.invalid #msg:before {
    content: '\0026A0';
    color: red;
}
form.valid #submit:hover {
    background-color: #009FFD;
    color: #423d3d;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class=""> <!-- form starts as neither valid or invalid -->
<p class="font">
    <span id="movePassword">Password</span>
</p>

<input id="password" type="password" name="password"
       placeholder="Password.." required>

<p class="font">
    <span id="movePassword">Confirm Password</span>
</p>

<input id="confirm_password" type="password" name="password"
        placeholder="Confirm.." onkeyup="check();" required>
<span id="msg"></span>

<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit"
       value="SIGN UP" id="submit">
</form>
```

The `<p class="font">` prompts really should use `<label for="password">` -- that's what label is for -- then style them with CSS, and `class="font"` is not very descriptive; classes should describe the *state* of something, or what it ***is***, not how it looks, so if you're not using `<label>` it might be `<p class="label">`

Comment: Thank you that really helped! Could you please care to explain the CSS part, I didn't really understand the content part

Comment: Sure @Makeyka - there are CSS pseudo-elements [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and `:after` which can be placed before/after elements, so my CSS is essentially adding an element _before_ the `#msg` element. In those CSS generated elements, you can set the [`content:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/content) of — what is in — the element.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because [mouseenter and mouseleave events don't work on disabled elements](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2558). When the passwords do not match, you disable the submit button, which means `mouseleave` never gets fired and the styles are never returned to normal.

You can fix this by using the css `enabled` and `hover` properties instead of jquery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

In your css, add this rule:

```
#submit:enabled:hover {
  background-color: #009FFD;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: 423d3d;
}
```

And in your javascript, remove your event listeners:

```
var check = function() {

   if (document.getElementById("password").value == document.getElementById("confirm_password").value) {
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = "#009FFD"; // Green
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "&#10004"; // Sign
       document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false; // Able to login (passwords match)
   } else {
       document.getElementById("msg").style.color = "red"; 
       document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "&#9888"; // Sign
       document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true; // Unable to login (passwords do not match)
   }

}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GewYQN)

Comment: Thank you, however, if you notice the button is changing colors even when both inputs are empty. The button must turn green only when the both passwords match

Comment: @Makeyka To fix that simply disable the submit button when both password fields are empty. You probably want to be doing that anyways, right?

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this is to run the check() function again on keyup:

```
<input id="password" onkeyup="check()" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password.." onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Password..'" required>
```

Comment: This does solve a bug, but not the bug that the question is asking about.